# Add parameter to drupal content page

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have drupal content page url for specific view

```
?q=content/74055
```

i want my url as

```
?q=content/74055&type=nip
```

how can i add type=nip parameter

Comment: (y) it is great question. I am also researching on it from 3 days now i got this question. can any body please answer it asap.

Comment: hi. can you give more details ? when you like the parameter to be there ? i guess this can be done from a .htaccess file or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it through following steps

login to your drupal admin panel and go to edit view option

1. add new field content: path
2. uncheck "Create a label" option for it
3. check "Exclude from display" option for it
4. Now edit field name on which you want to add link
5. choose "LINK IMAGE TO" option as "Nothing" for it
6. Now in section of "Rewrite results" check "Output this field as a link" option
7. paste "[path]&type=nip" in Link Path input field.

Answer (score 2):

this rule works for you

```
RewriteRule ^/?q=content/([0-9]+) /?q=content/$1&nip=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one in rewrite rule

RewriteRule ^/?q=content/([0-9]+) /?q=content/$1&nip=1